# Apparmor permission for libvirt-qemu

Tags: virtualization, qemu, apparmor, virt-manager

I am trying to run custom build qemu with libvirt. However, every time it fails due to apparmor permission.

dmesg shows that:

```
[   82.818348] audit: type=1400 audit(1563507497.685:181): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="libvirt-ec642fe5-8e5c-4d4a-ada7-b8562396d477" name="/home/probir/Downloads/qemu/qemu_kognizance/qemu_pinning/build_static/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64" pid=2235 comm="libvirtd" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=64055 ouid=1000
```

How can I instruct apparmor to allow custom-built qemu-system-x86_64?

Answer (score 0):

It detects that it has to run under the qemu profile (libvirt instructs things to recognize that). The profile for that is in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu`.

In newer versions of Ubuntu you will have `/etc/apparmor.d/local/abstractions/libvirt-qemu` which will take your overrides to avoid conflicts on packaging upgrades. In earler versions you still need to modify `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu` directly.

A rule for the deny that you see would be

```
/home/probir/Downloads/qemu/qemu_kognizance/qemu_pinning/build_static/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 rmix,
```

If you need more rules read the [apparmor rules guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) and the links from there.